# Как передать массив из родительского компонента в дочерний vue js

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть массив и форма. При клике на кнопку создания внутри родительского компонента и на кнопку редактирования внутри компонента со списком, у меня динамически должна появляться форма. Логика такая, если хочу добавить новое имя, `id` соответственно равняется `null`, если `id !== null`, то поле редактируется. Как "скормить" моей форме элемент массива, чтобы уже исходя из данных, что `id = null` или `id !==null`, я мог отображать форму с нужным лейблом?

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

const MyForm = {
  template: `<form v-if="nameIsCreate || nameIsEdit">
    <input id="form"
      type="text" 
      :value="name"
      @input="$emit('input', $event)"
      @keyup.enter="save()" 
    />
    <label for="form" v-if="nameIsCreate">создать имя</label>
    <label v-if="nameIsEdit" for="form">изменить имя</label>
  </form>`,
  name: 'my-form',
  model: {
    prop: "name"
  },
  props: ['nameIsCreate', 'nameIsEdit'],
  methods: {
    save: function() {
      this.$emit("save");
    }
  }
};

const MyList = {
  template: `
  <div>
    <span>{{personName.name}}</span>
    <button  @click="nameEdited()">edit</button>
  </div>`,
  name: 'my-list',
  props: {
    personName: {
      type: Object,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nameEdited: function(id) {
      this.$emit('nameEdited', id)
    },
  }
};

const App = {
    template: `
  <div>
  <button @click="createFormOpened()">create</button>
  <my-form 
    @save="saveName" 
    v-model="name" 
    :nameIsEdit="nameIsEdit" 
    :nameIsCreate="nameIsCreate"
  />
  <my-list 
    v-for="personName in persons"
    :key="personName.id" 
    :personName="personName" 
    @nameEdited="editFormOpened()"
  /> 
  </div>
  `,
    components: {
      'my-form': MyForm,
      'my-list': MyList
    },
    data() {
      return {
        nameIsEdit: false,
        nameIsCreate: false,
        name: '',
        person: {
          id: null, 
          name: ''
        },
        persons: [{
          id: 0,
          name: 'Ivan'
        },  {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Alex'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: 'John'
        }, ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      saveName() {
        if (this.persons.id === null) { 
          this.person = {
          name: ''
          }
        this.persons.push(this.person)
        } else {
        this.persons = this.persons.find(item => item.id === id)
        let index = this.persons.findIndex(item => item.id === person.id)
        this.persons.splice(index, 1, person)
        }
      },
      editFormOpened() {
        this.name = '';
        this.nameIsCreatenameIsEdit = false;
        this.nameIsEdit = !this.nameIsEdit;
      },
      createFormOpened: function() {
        this.name = '';
        this.nameIsEdit = false;
        this.nameIsCreate = !this.nameIsCreate;
      },
    }};

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        App
      },
      template: `<app></app>`
    })
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak></div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10'></script>
```

Comment: В коде масса синтаксических и логических ошибок (перечислять не буду, см. консоль после добавления `div#app`) - перед тем как решать задачу передачи массива, стоит сначала исправить их.

Comment: @yar85 я вроде подправил, но ошибка все равно одна есть. Ссылается на определенную строку, а у меня такой даже нет...позже понял в чем проблема, сейчас дело уже в другом. Не прогружаются компоненты..С чем это может быть связано, не подскажешь?

Comment: Скобка где-то не закрыта (а может и не одна). Я тоже пытался пофиксить этот код, но с планшетника неудобно и медленно: за полчаса возни не разгреб все ошибки, после чего и написал предыдущий коммент... А по тексту вопроса логика алгоритма не очень понятна :/ (например, зачем передавать именно массив и именно через событие, если можно этот массив через `props` забиндить дочернему компоненту из родительского, и индекс элемента тоже).

Comment: @yar85 скобки перепроверил уже несколько раз...Не прогружаются компоненты все равно. Я и хочу избавиться от перменных  `nameIsCreate`и `nameIsEdit` и выводить лейбл уже относительно айдишника. Передавал через props..Возможно внутри компонента дочернего, куда прокинул объект (массив, действительно, целиком прокидывать нет смысла), просто неправильно обращаюсь к свойству, но и ошибок нет, и выводит 2 лейбла одновременно

Comment: @yar85 заменил camelCase- именование внутри Арр на snake-case и компоненты заработали

Comment: Нажимаю на `edit` в нескольких строках, и происходит жесть. Может лучше словами объяснишь почетче, как это должно работать? Как я понял: при нажатии `edit`, в инпут должно попадать значение `name` из объекта в массиве `persons`, а при нажатии `create` - инпут должен быть пустым. Правильно? (если нет, уточни что именно неправильно)

Comment: @yar85 да, я вижу сам, что там происходит какой-то капец. Сам сейчас запутался. Извини пожалуйста, я начинающий еще, хочу разобраться... 
Ты написал все верно: при редактировании - в `v-model` попадает `name`, при создании в `v-model` попадает пустая строка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102602/discussion-between-yar85-and-ivan-navi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const LabeledEdit = {
  template: `
    <div class="labeled-edit">
      <label>
        <span class="label">{{ label }}</span>
        <input autofocus ref="input" v-model="value"
          @input="$emit('input', $event)" @keyup.enter="applyInput" 
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    value: ''
  }),
  props: {
    data: Object,
    valueKey: String, 
    label: String
  },
  methods: {
    applyInput(e) {
      const newData = { ...this.data, [this.valueKey]: this.value };
      this.$emit('save', newData);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.value = this.data[this.valueKey];
    this.$refs.input.focus();
  },
  name: 'LabeledEdit'
};

const MyList = {
  template: `
    <div class="my-list">
      <div class="row" v-for="person in persons" :key="person.id">
        <span class="pid">{{ person.id + '.' }}</span>
        <labeled-edit v-if="person === personForEdit"
          :data="person" valueKey="name"
          @save="changePersonData(person, $event)"
        ></labeled-edit>
        <template v-else>
          <span class="name">{{ person.name }}</span>
          <button @click="personForEdit = person">Edit</button>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    personForEdit: null
  }),
  props: {
    persons: { type: Array }
  },
  methods: {
    changePersonData(person, changedPerson) {
      const personIdx = this.persons.findIndex(p => p.id === person.id);
      if (personIdx < 0)
        throw new Error('No person found for changePersonName');
      this.persons.splice(personIdx, 1, { ...changedPerson });
      this.personForEdit = null;
    },
  },
  components: { LabeledEdit },
  name: 'MyList'
};

const App = {
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <div class="row create">
        <labeled-edit v-if="showEdit"
          :data="newPerson" valueKey="name" label="Создать:"
          @save="addPerson"
        ></labeled-edit>
        <button v-else class="btn-create" @click="createPerson">Create</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <my-list :persons="persons"></my-list>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    showEdit: false,
    newPerson: null,
    persons: [
      { id: 0, name: 'Ivan' },
      { id: 1, name: 'Alex' },
      { id: 2, name: 'John' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    createPerson() {
      const lastId = this.persons.reduce((r, p) => r = Math.max(r, p.id), -1);
      this.newPerson = { id: lastId + 1, name: '' };
      this.showEdit = true;
    },
    addPerson(person) {
      this.persons.push({ ...person });
      this.showEdit = false;
    }
  },
  components: { MyList, LabeledEdit },
  name: 'App'
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: `<app></app>`
});
```

```css
body, input { font: 1rem sans-serif; }
hr { padding: 0; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }

.app { max-width: 300px; }
  .app * { box-sizing: border-box; }
 
.labeled-edit,
.labeled-edit input { width: 100%; }
.row.create .labeled-edit input { width: auto; }

.btn-create { margin: 0.1rem 0 0.1rem 1rem; }

.my-list { width: 100%; }
  .my-list .row { display: flex; align-content: center; padding: 0.4rem 1rem; }
  .my-list .row:nth-child(even) { background: #eee7; }
    .my-list .labeled-edit { margin-left: -2px; }
    .my-list button { flex: 0 0 auto; }
    .my-list .pid   { flex: 0 0 auto; margin: 3px 0.5em 3px 0; color: #aaa; }
    .my-list .name  { flex: 1 0 auto; margin: 3px 0; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

---

С использованием одного компонента ввода - и для создания, и для редактирования:

```js
const LabeledEdit = {
  template: `
    <div class="labeled-edit">
      <label>
        <span class="label">{{ label }}</span>
        <input autofocus ref="input" v-model="value"
          @input="$emit('input', $event)" @keyup.enter="applyInput" 
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    value: ''
  }),
  props: {
    data: Object,
    valueKey: String, 
    label: String
  },
  methods: {
    applyInput(e) {
      const newData = { ...this.data, [this.valueKey]: this.value };
      this.$emit('save', newData);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.value = this.data[this.valueKey];
    this.$refs.input.focus();
  },
  name: 'LabeledEdit'
};

const MyList = {
  template: `
    <div class="my-list">
      <div class="row" v-for="person in persons" :key="person.id">
        <span class="pid">{{ person.id + '.' }}</span>
        <span class="name">{{ person.name }}</span>
        <button @click="$emit('edit', person)">Edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    persons: { type: Array }
  },
  components: { LabeledEdit },
  name: 'MyList'
};

const App = {
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <div class="row create">
        <labeled-edit v-if="showEdit"
          :data="personData" valueKey="name"
          :label="creatingPerson ? 'Создать:' : 'Изменить:'"
          @save="applyChanges"
        ></labeled-edit>
        <button v-else class="btn-create" @click="createPerson">Create</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <my-list :persons="persons" @edit="editPerson"></my-list>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    showEdit: false,
    personData: null,
    creatingPerson: false, 
    persons: [
      { id: 0, name: 'Ivan' },
      { id: 1, name: 'Alex' },
      { id: 2, name: 'John' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    createPerson() {
      this.creatingPerson = true; 
      const lastId = this.persons.reduce((r, p) => r = Math.max(r, p.id), -1);
      this.personData = { id: lastId + 1, name: '' };
      this.showEdit = true;
    },
    editPerson(person) {
      this.creatingPerson = false; 
      this.personData = person;
      this.showEdit = true;
    },
    applyChanges(person) {
      if (!this.creatingPerson) {
        const idx = this.persons.findIndex(p => p.id === person.id); 
        this.$set(this.persons, idx, { ...person }); 
      } else {
        this.persons.push({ ...person });
      }
      this.showEdit = false;
    }
  },
  components: { MyList, LabeledEdit },
  name: 'App'
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: `<app></app>`
});
```

```css
body, input { font: 1rem sans-serif; }
hr { padding: 0; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }

.app { max-width: 300px; }
  .app * { box-sizing: border-box; }
 
.labeled-edit { width: 100%; }
  .labeled-edit label { display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; align-content: center; }
    .labeled-edit span  { line-height: 1.6em; }
    .labeled-edit input { flex: 1 1 auto; min-width: 0; margin-left: 0.2em; }

.btn-create { margin: 0.1rem 0 0.1rem 1rem; }

.my-list { width: 100%; }
  .my-list .row { display: flex; align-content: center; padding: 0.4rem 1rem; }
  .my-list .row:nth-child(even) { background: #eee7; }
    .my-list button { flex: 0 0 auto; }
    .my-list .pid   { flex: 0 0 auto; margin: 3px 0.5em 3px 0; color: #aaa; }
    .my-list .name  { flex: 1 0 auto; margin: 3px 0; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо за потраченное время на развернутый ответ к моему вопросу

Comment: @IvanNavi, Пожалуйста. Нюанс: у второго варианта не учтена ситуация нажатия "Edit" при активном редактировании... если кнопки не будут блокироваться, то вместо присвоения в `mounted`, можно связать `name` из объекта в `props` со свойством элемента через бинд вычисляемого свойства (возвращающего `name`) - так значение инпута будет обновляться реактивно.